# Best adjectives to describe due dates?

Tags: technical

When talking about multiple assignments, what's a good way to describe the next task that is due? For example, say I sort a list of assignments in the order they are due. How can I describe the task on the top of the list?

"The task with the closest due date." ?
"The task with the next due date." ?
 
"The next task due." ?

The tasks aren't necessarily related to each other; that is why I'm not sure if the last option will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are distinct notions relating to scheduling, requiring appropriate words:

**Order/Sequence**: next

**Closeness in time**: closest

**Importance**: most /important/critical/demanding/

Thus, both:

*"Our **next** task is the ..."*

*"Our **most time-critical** task is the ..."*

> Exploring the Internet: A Technical Travelogue - Page 32 Carl Malamud
>   - 1992 - ‎Full view
>
> Getting the cables up was **the most time-critical task**, but plenty
>   of work still remained. Cables had to be connected to equipment racks,
>   connectors tested, the backbone had to be tested, vendors had a
>   million questions, the Internet link ...
>
> -
>
> Financial Applications using Excel Add-in Development in C ... Steve
>   Dalton - 2007 -
>
> If moved to the end, **the next task in the list** is always the next
>   to be processed. If a modified task were left in its previous
>   position, the algorithm to pick the next task would have to start
>   looking at the top of the list every time, just in case a task ...
>
> -
>
> The Rise to Power of the Chinese Communist Party: ... - Page 596 Tony
>   Saich, ‎Benjamin Yang - 1995
>
> ... be consolidated with Lianchen and Changting. Also, we should link
>   these areas with Ninghua and Qingliu and move in the direction of
>   Yongan. This is **the most urgent task in our plan** to consolidate
>   west Fujian and to develop north Fujian.
>
> -
>
> Project Monitor To Do List Excel and Word Spreadsheet ...
>
> Apr 9, 2014 - Therefore instead of caring about the future tasks, it
>   is recommended to take serious notes about **the next due task in the
>   project** and evaluating the instant outcome to see whether the
>   orientation is right or not.

Comment: Thanks! So do you think "the task with the closest due date" is the best way to say this? When you say "next" is for order/sequence, does that work for events too? For example, what about when you're watching TV and they say something "coming up next is The Voice", etc. ?

Comment: Updated. Google Books is your friend for testing patterns :-)

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. "Next task in the list..." is what I was looking for I think. That one will work for me.